# How to turn dictionary with varied list pairs, into dataframe columns and rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary, with keys that are intended to be an index, and multiple list pairs. How can i turn that dictionary into a dataframe, where the first item in the list is a column in the dataframe and the second item is the respective column value? Each key has a varied number of list pairs.

My list looks something like this:

```
{1234: [['Facebook','www.facebook.com/4countyelectric'], ['Name', '4 County Electric'], ['Phone', '1-800-555-1111']], 
1235: [['Name', '3 Phases Energy'], ['Twitter', '@3phases'], ['Phone', '1-800-444-1111'],
1236: [['Phone', '585-719-1234'], ['Outage Number', '585-719-1235'], ['Name', 'Rochester Gas & Electric']]}
```

I'm trying to create a dataframe that looks like this, and takes into account whether or not the first list pair item is currently a dataframe column:

```
Index  Name                       Twitter  Facebook           Phone            Outage Number

1234   4 County Electric           Null    www.facebook.com/  1-800-555-1111   Null
1235   3 Phases Energy            @3phases Null               1-800-444-1111   Null
1236   Rochester Gas & Electric    Null    Null               585-719-1234     585-719-1235
```

How can this be done?

Each time I've tried I keep getting "list index out of range" as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert your dictionary of nested lists to a dictionary of dictionaries. Then it's easy to convert it to a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {1234: [['Facebook','www.facebook.com/4countyelectric'], ['Name', '4 County Electric'], ['Phone', '1-800-555-1111']],
1235: [['Name', '3 Phases Energy'], ['Twitter', '@3phases'], ['Phone', '1-800-444-1111']], 1236: [['Phone', '585-719-1234'], ['Outage Number', '585-719-1235'], ['Name', 'Rochester Gas & Electric']]}
    
for k,v in dic.items():
    inner_dic = {}
    for item in v:
        inner_dic[item[0]] = item[1]
    dic[k] = inner_dic
    
df = pd.DataFrame(dic).transpose()
    
#to display all columns, I truncated the facebook address.
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', 10):
    print (df)

#output:
[3 rows x 5 columns]
               Facebook                      Name           Phone   Twitter  \
1234  www.facebook.com/         4 County Electric  1-800-555-1111       NaN   
1235                NaN           3 Phases Energy  1-800-444-1111  @3phases   
1236                NaN  Rochester Gas & Electric    585-719-1234       NaN   

     Outage Number  
1234           NaN  
1235           NaN  
1236  585-719-1235
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested this on a subset and it worked as intended. What can I do if the list contains one item and i want it to just be nan?

Comment: If the list has only one item (one sublist), it will include that item in the dataframe and enter NaN for all the missing items in that row. Is that what you are asking? By the way, consider accepting the answer if it has worked for you.